# How to conceal being a vampire in a party of Clerics and Paladins?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead

In an upcoming campaign, the DM and I have spoken in private about my character being a vampire in disguise. With a Rogue's set of skills, disguises, impersonations, and deceit should be achievable. The DM will be doing their best to treat me as a human character to see how far was can extend this ruse. The various oddities of a Vampire, such as feeding, being immune to healing, and not being able to enter a house without permission could easily be role played. Our setting is Barovia, so direct sunlight should not be an issue.

The one problem I don't know how to resolve, is how to deal with both a Cleric and Paladin who both can detect undead and evil with relative ease.

What sorts of items/excuses/backstory might my character use to either conceal or explain away any suspicion?

I wanted to consider options that were consistent with the rules/magical items available.

Comment: I'd be less worried about detect alignment. It wouldn't be too hard to pass that off as a curse (which wouldn't really be lieing if you are playing a good vampire). I'd be more worried about your allies trying to "save you from death" by healing you after you take massive damage. (because vampires are undead) I think that will be the biggest danger/giveaway, and not sure how to tackle that as a rogue.

Comment: @Tezra How about "don't get hit"?

Comment: @MarkWells "Famous last words". I know HP > 0 is the best plan ever, but I have yet to play with any group that could stick to that plan. =P

Answer (score 35):

You want the second-level wizard spell [*Nystul's magic aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/nystuls-magic-aura) (listed in the SRD as [*arcanist's magic aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura)). This spell can disguise your creature type. The duration is 24 hours, but if someone casts it on you 30 days in a row, it becomes permanent until dispelled.

Comment: @Gandalfmeansme There are "generic" versions of all the spells with a specific mage's name in their name, presumably so you can use them in a setting that doesn't include those specific mages in its lore. The spells are identical except for the name.

Comment: As a note, if your backstory is that you are a vampire in hiding, your DM might allow you to start the campaign with a permanent magic aura spell already in place, with the assumption that you convinced or coerced someone with the spell into casting it on you some time in the past.

Comment: You might want to add that *Nystul's/arcanist's magic aura* specifically calls out "a paladin's Divine Sense" as being fooled by its "Mask" effect.

Comment: @ryan - or maybe having something to do with copyright.

Answer (score 25):

### Against spells and magic there are a number of ways.

The paladin’s Divine Sense ability seems to be erroneously defined. In its definition it is not called out as magical by the rules detailed in the [Sage Advice Compendium 2017](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) (Is the breath weapon of a dragon magical? p5). However, within the definition of a spell, namely *Nystul's Magic Aura* it clearly calls it out as such.

PHB 263 (emphasis mine).

***Nystul's Magic Aura***

> You change the way the target appears to spells and **magical effects** that detect creature types, such as a **paladin’s Divine Sense** or the trigger of a symbol spell.

So it seems clearly intended to be magical, with that pseudo errata the rest of the following options work just fine if you consider the ability to also be divination in nature. Since the root word for divination is 'divine' it is not a stretch and with the added precident that *Nystul's Magic Aura* is intended to foil divination specifically I think it is intended.

It does have a flaw though. If one of your companions tries to dispel that Fear or other some spell on you it will immediately remove your "disguise".

***Nondetection***.

> For the duration, you hide a target that you touch from **divination
> magic.**

There is an item that pretty much duplicates Nondetection as well and it is uncommon so accessible starting at lower hoard levels.

**Amulet of Proof Against Detection and Location** (uncommon). Long name, amazing results.

> While wearing this amulet, you are hidden from divination magic. you can't be targeted by such magic or perceived through magical scrying sensors.

This and Nondetection have the bonus side effect of you being unable to be scried, and not only that if your companion is scried and you are in proximity you would be invisible through that sensor.

**Ring of Mind Shielding.**  (uncommon)

> While wearing this ring, you are immune to magic that allows other creatures to read your thoughts, determine whether you are lying, know your alignment, **or know your creature type**.

Personally, I would recommend this last one. It has the added bonus of foiling magic that would catch you in a lie. It won't block role-playing it out and them catching you in a lie by conventional means but things like *Zone of Truth* would be useless against you. Then cast *Nystul's Magic Aura* until it is permanent on the ring itself, then cause the ring to be invisible (built into the item itself).

#### The healing issue

It is important to note that as a vampire you would regenerate and are unaffected by healing magic. This could probably be pulled off as a bluff. Get yourself a platinum ring and have *Nystul's Magic Aura* cast till permanent to mimic a Ring of Regeneration. You can simply inform the healers that you will be fine because of the item and to not waste valuable resources on you but rather heal the rest of the party. Now if you are reduced to zero and turn to mist there could be additional issues obviously. The fact that you won't be within vicinity of your coffin is also problematic.

Comment: Maybe the PC can disguise their coffin as a weird camp bed and bring it along?